# Guitar picking hand motion when playing pull-offs

Tags: guitar, technique

Which of strumming patterns below is best to use most of the time when playing pull-offs?

I learned using second one, suits me fine with regards to technique (it is more economical), but since pattern varies a lot in my playing it is harder for me to keep time. How should I approach this problem?

```
        v   v
    E|---------
    B|--5p3----
    G|------4--
    D|---------
    A|---------
    E|---------
```

vs

```
        v   ^
    E|---------
    B|--5p3----
    G|------4--
    D|---------
    A|---------
    E|---------
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of your patterns are valid, but they differ in the efficiency of your hand movements.

If you play the first pattern with a "sweep" stroke then it will be the most efficient. This is a sightly harder technique as it means means playing a single upstroke instead of two consecutive upstrokes. Its harder to get the timing right but can lead to a very fast technique for arpeggios etc if you extend it across multiple strings.

To help keep either pattern in time I'd recommend:

- Use a metronome. Start at a comfortable tempo and then increase gradually.
- Play the pattern as part of a longer sequence.
- Repeat the sequence on different strings and up and down the neck.
- Play both patterns in alternation.

I'd say it will help most if you see both patterns as useful techniques to learn, rather than it being an either/or type of choice.

Comment: I removed the pick stroke after realizing it could be taken not just as a hand motion which was my intention.